# How to close UIWebView created programmatically?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, uibutton

I have the following code to create UIWebView programmatically and create UIButton on top of it to close it. The creation is OK, but the problem I can't refer back to the created UIWebView to close it from the button!

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[webView addSubview:button];

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
????
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In ViewController.m

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

// tag will be used to get this webview later
webView.tag=55;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(close:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[webView addSubview:button];





- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {

    [[self.view viewWithTag:55] removeFromSuperview];


}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and managed to compile it successfully, but at runtime when I clicked on the close button; it crashed and got the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a17e20'

Comment: in ur .h file declare this - (IBAction)close:(id)sender;

Comment: the "aMethod" is defined as an additional button target for the action where the user just touches the button - can be used for changing the color of the button to show that the app sees that it has been pressed. If needed, define - (IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender; If not needed, delete the first call to addTarget from the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your webView as an ivar of your UIViewController.

Right now you have it as a local variable to the method so you can't refer to it outside that method.  Instead, declare it in your interface section of your .h file and you'll be able to access it from all your class methods.

And don't forget to release it in your dealloc method!

Comment: I declared *webview in the interface and managed to compiled it successfully, but at runtime when I clicked on the close button; it crashed and got the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a17e20'

Answer (score 0):

The web view is the button's superview so you should be able to get it like this,

```
UIWebView * webView = [(UIButton *)sender superview];
```

Now you can do `removeFromSuperview` or something else to make it disappear.

**Edit**

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    UIWebView * webView = [(UIButton *)sender superview];
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more where to add this code? Please refer to my code.

Comment: it didn't work! It throughs this error: Incompatible pointer types initializing UIWebView *, and even at runtime it crashed!

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"%@", webView);` before the `removeFromSuperview` statement and tell me what it prints? And change the first line to `UIWebView * webView = (UIWebView *)[(UIButton *)sender superview];`.

Comment: It crashed before reaching NSLog! The webView loaded successfully, but only when button clicked it crashed! BTW, thanks a lot for your follow-up, appreciated!

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5824710'
Do you want the rest of the details log?

Comment: No, where are you calling `aMethod:`? It seems be getting invoked somehow. Or did you set the `action:` to `aMethod:` instead of `close:`? This is a wild guess though but if you are explicitly calling `aMethod:` somewhere, it would be nice if you can add the related code there with a bit of explanation as to how it is invoked.

Comment: Many thanks @Deepak, the crash was because of the aMethod, I forgot to change it based on my function name :/ Ok now I have another problem :) When the webView loaded, my main tabs bar removed from the display!

Comment: I found the reason, I have this line in my code when webView created [self presentModalViewController:self animated:YES]; Thanks man for your great follow-up :)

Answer (score -1):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
    NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"https://google.com/login?"]) {
        NSLog(@"move to another view or close the web view");
        [portfolioWebView removeFromSuperview];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```